# Unable to fill the box using css in JavaScipt

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

[image]

I am making a quiz website using javascript, and with the help of css I am trying to fill the box with color as the quiz goes on. However the code I am writing is not exactly working. any suggestions? I think the **game.js** class is unable to find **progressBarFull**. any sort of help will be appreciated.

//////game.js/////

```
const question = document.getElementById('question');
const choices = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('choice-text'));
const progressText = document.getElementById('progressText');
const scoreText = document.getElementById('score');
const progressBarFull = document.getElementById('progressBarFull');

let currentQuestion = {};
let acceptingAnswer = false;
let Score = 0 ;
let QuestionCounter = 0;
let AvailableQuestion = [];

let questions = [
    {
         question:"Inside which HTML element do we put JavaScript?",
         choice1: "<script>",
         choice2: "<javascript>",
         choice3: "<js>",
         choice4: "<scripting>",
         answer: 1
        },
        {
         question:"What is correct syntax for referreing to an external script called xxx.js",
         choice1: "<script href='xxx.js'>",
         choice2: "<script name='xxx.js'>",
         choice3: "<script src='xxx.js'>",
         choice4: "<script file='xxx.js'>",
         answer: 3
        },
        {
         question:"How do you write Hello in an alert box",
         choice1: "msgbox('Hello World')",
         choice2: "alertbox('Hello World')",
         choice3: "msg('Hello World')",
         choice4: "alert('Hello World')",
         answer: 4
        },
]


// Constants

const CORRECT_BONUS = 10;
const MAX_QUESTIONS = 3;
const INCORRECT = 10;

startgame = (  ) =>{
    QuestionCounter=0;
    Score=0;
    AvailableQuestion=[...questions];
    console.log(AvailableQuestion);
    getNewQuestion();
};

getNewQuestion =()=> {
    if(AvailableQuestion.length == 0 || question>= MAX_QUESTIONS){
        // Go to the endpage
        return window.location.assign('/end.html');
    }
    QuestionCounter++;
    progressText.innerText = `Question ${QuestionCounter} / ${MAX_QUESTIONS}`;

    
    // Update The ProgressBar
    progressBarFull.style.width = `${(QuestionCounter / MAX_QUESTIONS) * 100}
    %`
    console.log((QuestionCounter / MAX_QUESTIONS) * 100)


    const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * AvailableQuestion.length);
    currentQuestion = AvailableQuestion[questionIndex];
    question.innerText = currentQuestion.question;


    // foreach iterates through the choices
    choices.forEach( choice => {
        const number = choice.dataset['number']; 
        // getting number from data-number --- game.html
        choice.innerText = currentQuestion['choice' + number]
    })
    AvailableQuestion.splice(questionIndex, 1);

    acceptingAnswer = true
};

choices.forEach(choice => {
    choice.addEventListener("click", e=> {
        if(!acceptingAnswer) return;
        
        
        acceptingAnswer = false;
        const selectedChoice = e.target;
        const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset["number"];
        
        // Different ways of using conditions
        // const classToApply = 'incorrect';
        // if(selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer){
        //     classToApply = 'correct;'
        // }

        const classToApply = selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? 'correct' : 'incorrect';
        if (classToApply === 'correct'){
            incrementScore(CORRECT_BONUS)
        }
        else{
            decrementScore(INCORRECT)
        }
        // console.log(classToApply)

        selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply)
        setTimeout(() => {
            selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply)
            getNewQuestion()
            
        }, 250);

       

        // console.log(selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer)
    })

})

incrementScore = num => {
    Score += num;
    scoreText.innerText = Score;
}

decrementScore = num => {
    Score -= num;
    scoreText.innerText = Score;
}

startgame()
```

/////game.html///

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Game - Play</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="game" class="justify-center flex-column">
            <div id="hud">
                <div id="hud-item">
                    <p id="progressText" class="hud-prefix">
                        Question
                    </p>
                    <div id="progressBar">
                        <div id="progressBarFull"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div id="hud-item">
                    <p class="hud-prefix">
                        Score
                    </p>
                    <h1 class="hud-mainText" id="score">
                        0
                    </h1>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <h2 id="question">
                Answer to this question?
            </h2>
            <div class="choice-container">
                <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
                <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">Choice 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-container">
                <p class="choice-prefix">B</p>
                <p class="choice-text" data-number="2">Choice 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-container">
                <p class="choice-prefix">C</p>
                <p class="choice-text" data-number="3">Choice 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-container">
                <p class="choice-prefix">D</p>
                <p class="choice-text" data-number="4">Choice 4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

//////game.css////

```
.choice-container{
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    border:0.1rem solid rgb(86, 235, 0.25);
    background-color: white;
}

.choice-container:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0.4rem 1.4rem 0 rgb(86, 165, 235, 0.5);
    transform: translate(-0.1rem);
    transition: transfor 150ms;
}

.choice-prefix{
    padding:1.5rem 2.5rem;
    background-color: #56a5eb;
    color: white;

}

.choice-text{
    padding: 1.5rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.correct{
    background-color: #28a745;
}

.incorrect{
    background-color: #dc3545;
}

/* HUD */
#hud {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.hud-prefix{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.hud-main-text{
    text-align: center;
}

#progressBar{
    width: 20rem;
    height: 4rem;
    border: 0.3rem solid #56a5eb;
    margin-top: 0.9rem;

}

#progressBarFull{
    height: 3.4rem;
    background-color:#56a5eb;
    width: 0%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please clarify what exactly is not working. Your example in minimal, so it's hard to know what you have tried or what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Irrespective of other issues, the issue is that you are setting an invalid style on progressBarFull.

You have whitespace in your js:

`` progressBarFull.style.width = `${(QuestionCounter / MAX_QUESTIONS) * 100} %` ``

This results in setting an invalid style, which won't even show up in the DOM in something like inspect.  For a percentage (%) specifier, it needs to be right after the numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example that might work for you. This is using jQuery, yet can also be converted to Vanilla JS.

```js
$(function() {
  function setProgress(current, total) {
    var perc = Math.floor((current / total) * 100);
    $("#progressBarFull").css("width", perc + "%");
  }

  $("button").click(function() {
    setProgress($(this).val(), 3);
    $(this).prop("disabled", true).next().prop("disabled", false);
  });
});
```

```css
#hud {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.hud-prefix {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.hud-main-text {
  text-align: center;
}

#progressBar {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border: 0.3rem solid #56a5eb;
  margin-top: 0.9rem;
}

#progressBarFull {
  height: 3.4rem;
  background-color: #56a5eb;
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hud">
  <div id="hud-item">
    <p id="progressText" class="hud-prefix">
      Question
    </p>
    <div id="progressBar">
      <div id="progressBarFull"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="hud-item">
    <p class="hud-prefix">
      Score
    </p>
    <h1 class="hud-mainText" id="score">
      0
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
<button value="1">Answer 1</button>
<button value="2" disabled="true">Answer 2</button>
<button value="3" disabled="true">Answer 3</button>
```